# Pointwise convergence of sets

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm stuck with this problem for a while. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Given that the sets $E_n$ converges pointwise to another set $E$, in the sense that the indicator functions $1_{E_n}$ converges pointwise to the indicator function $1_E$, show that $E$ can be written as countable unions and intersections  of the sets $E_n$.

The hint given in the book suggests to use the identity $1_E(x)=\liminf_{n \to \infty}1_{E_n}(x)$ or $1_E(x)=\limsup_{n \to \infty}1_{E_n}(x)$, but I can't see a clear-cut attack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. There are definitions of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ for a sequence of sets.

If  $(E_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of subsets of some set $X$ then 
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} E_n:= \bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \left( \bigcup_{n\ge N} E_n \right)\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\liminf_{n \to \infty} E_n = \bigcup_{N=1}^\infty \left(\bigcap_{n \ge N} E_n\right).$$
Are these definitions related to your problem?

Comment: Yeah. That helps! Now it's easy to show that $1_{E}(x)=\liminf_{n \to \infty} 1_{E_n}(x) \implies E=\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\big(\bigcap_{n \geq N} E_n \big)$. The definition rang the bells.